# Appending a WHERE clause to a Doctrine_Query

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I have a situation where I want to assemble a Doctrine select query based on weather certain params are empty or not  For example, if there was a $slug variable that was optional, i'd want something like this:

```
function get_bio($slug = '')
{
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Bio b');

     if (!empty($slug))
     {
          $q .= $q->where('b.slug = ?', $slug);
     }
 }
```

I know thats not the correct syntax, but how would I assemble something like that?

Comment: You should take a look at Doctrine's [QueryBuilder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating the query object as a string rather than an object.  Try this instead:

```
function get_bio($slug = '')
{
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Bio b');

     if (!empty($slug))
     {
          $q->where('b.slug = ?', $slug);
     }
 }
```

Note the call to `$q->where()` operates directly on the query object `$q`, so you do not have to assign the return value to anything (it returns a reference to the query object itself so that you can chain method calls).

Note also that if you are planning on adding multiple `where` clauses, you will probably want to use `andWhere()` instead of `where()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by dtj](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8955346/2)

---

Apparently, I wasn't too far off.  Here's the correct syntax:

```
function get_bio($slug = '')
{
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Bio b');

     if (!empty($slug))
     {
          $q = $q->where('b.slug = ?', $slug);
     }
 }
```

As simple as removing a dot :)

Comment: @dtj Technically, the `$q =` part is not even necessary. If you just do `$q->where(...)`, that will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do just two Queries? In my opinion it doesn't make sense that you do a function for this, but only my opinion. I would do it like this way:

```
if ($slug != NULL) {
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Bio b');
    ->where('b.slug = ?', $slug);
}
else {
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Bio b');
}
```

This is not the correct syntax too.

Comment: well unfortunately, there's 3 parameters in my situation.  So to account for all the permutations, i would need quite a few if/else statements.  Seems to be more efficient to just add to the query as needed